# storagegateway.ListGateways() returning "Invalid resource" with status code: 400

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-go, aws-storage-gateway

I am having trouble using the go sdk to list all of the storage gateways in a region using the following code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/storagegateway"
)

func newSess() (sess *session.Session) {
    sess, err := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
        Region: aws.String("us-east-2"),
    })

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error creating session: %s\n", err)
        return
    }

    return sess
}

func main() {
    sgw := storagegateway.New(newSess())

    input := &storagegateway.ListGatewaysInput{
        Limit:  aws.Int64(5),
        Marker: aws.String("1"),
    }

    result, err := sgw.ListGateways(input)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error listing gateways %s\n", err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println(result)

}
```

My environment is the following:

- **Go version:** 1.9.2 darwin/amd64
- **Operating system:** macOS 10.13.2
- **aws-sdk-go:** v1.12.63

The SDK is using the default profile specified in `~/.aws/config` as it should and the credentials are correct as well. Furthermore, I am able to list the gateways using the awscli alone.

This could very well be something simple that I have overlooked as I am no expert. That said, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's the full error output? Per the docs, "Use runtime type assertions with awserr.Error's Code and Message methods to get detailed information about the error."

Comment: Here is the full error output: `InvalidGatewayRequestException InvalidGatewayRequestException: Invalid resource
        status code: 400`

Comment: Well, I was unable to re-create your issue. So while waiting for somebody to work it out here, maybe you can mention it in the Github [issues page](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/issues)

Comment: @j8kster, Can you check this? Show me the error? https://play.golang.org/p/spCXy-zktgW. Use Your credential in `credentials.NewStaticCredentials("", "", "")`

Comment: @aerokite I ran the code that you provided using my credentials as instructed. Unfortunately, I still got the same error `Error listing gateways InvalidGatewayRequestException: Invalid resource status code: 400`

Comment: Are you using master for https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go

Comment: I have check with https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/releases/tag/v1.7.8

Comment: @aerokite I pulled the SDK down with the `go get -d github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/` command which in my understanding should grab the latest release.

Comment: I will also add that I packaged this code to run in an AWS lambda function now that go is supported and got the same results using an IAM role with proper access to the storage gateway resources as well as AWS's runtime and SDK version. I am however able to execute other calls such as `DescribeTapeArchives` successfully in the same runtime using the same session.

Comment: Can you share the exact aws CLI command which gives you the proper result?

Comment: @Anuruddha the aws CLI command is `aws storagegateway list-gateways`.

Comment: Does the gateway exist? Or started? "After the gateway is shutdown, you cannot call any other API except StartGateway, DescribeGatewayInformation, and ListGateways. For more information, see ActivateGateway. Your applications cannot read from or write to the gateway's storage volumes, and there are no snapshots taken. "

Comment: @strongjz Yes, the gateways exist, are activated, and started. I successfully get a list of them with the AWS CLI command, as well as the python SDK which I have tried now as well. Gateway operational state is reported as active and I am actively using these gateways in production.

Answer (score 0):

The example code seems to work as expected for me by simply removing the `Marker: aws.String("1")` line.